# Setting many variables in a PHP class

Tags: php, oop

I'm currently writing a PHP login script and trying to make it as secure as I can, currently the script is being made just as a matter of interest rather than having any practical application.  I've run across a slight problem I cannot overcome, it's more of which way is the best to do it rather than an actual problem though.  From a security standpoint I don't think it matters though, I'm just wondering which is the best way in general to do it and why.

In order for this class to work there are quite a few variables that need to be set up such as the table holding the users login details, the fields for their username and password, the type of encryption or hashing to use and quite a few others.  How would you suggest is the best way to set these?  Currently I can think of either setting them in the class constructors arguments, but there is quite a long list of what needs to be set or setting them as public static variables at the beginning of the class.  Which do you think is best and also why so I can understand the reasoning behind it.  If you have another idea better tha n my two I'd like to hear them as well.

Sorry if this has already been asked, I have tried searching but not found much; kind of hard to even know what to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One suggestion is to put the arguments into a single array.  Like

```
<?php
class Example
{
    # ...code here...

    public function __construct($args)
    {
        foreach($args as $key => $val)
        {
            switch($key)
            {
            case 'foo':
                # ...code here...
                break;
            case 'bar':
                # ...code here...
                break;
            default:
                # discard irrelevent elements
            }
        }
    }

    # ...code here...
}
```

Comment: I like that idea, using an array would be a lot cleaner and I could pass it to the constructor and perform some validation check on each variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you say table do you intend to have a database of user information? Once you verify a credential set you can pass a unique ID to the constructor and allow that to set the internal class properties when instanciated by querying the database. Alternatively, write a lot of setters and build each object as needed.

One thing about the encryption and similar settings, would they even be different per user? Could you consider setting these in a setting variable for all instances of the user class rather than setting it for each object.

Comment: Well the table that this class will be connecting to is the one holding the user credentials, the purpose of setting the variables here is to allow this class to know what table holds the user credentials and what fields hold their username and password.  I guess I'm trying to make this a bit of a self contained generic class that could be used on multiple sites if I were to use it in projects.  I hope that answers your question.

Your right the encryption used would likely stay the same for all the users, and that's a good suggestion.